# Choose an option from select in bash

Tags: shell-script, prompt, ruby

I am trying to run `gem uninstall bundler` through a bash script.
The issue occurs when I have multiple bundler versions installed. It prompts the number of versions, and last option is to uninstall all the bundler versions:-

```
root@testuser:/home/test# gem uninstall bundler -x

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. bundler-1.13.7
 2. bundler-1.16.0
 3. All versions
```

I want to input the number displayed in front of `All versions` text.

I know that I can do something like `echo -e '3' | gem uninstall bundler` but I do not know if the `All versions` option is displayed on 3, 4 or whichever number. Hence I am looking for a solution which can parse the select options and then enters the number in front of it.

Comment: It moves ahead and behaves as it should after entering 3. But, I do not know how to know that `All versions` is at #3.

Comment: Probably want something like expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using `gem uninstall` with an `-a` or `--all` option will uninstall all matching versions, as described in [the manual](https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-uninstall).

In your case:

```
gem uninstall bundler -a -x
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with the `gem uninstall bundler` but it may work for you.

```
#launch your process in a subshell and direct the subshell output to a file
#yours will probably read (gem uninstall bundler -x) > count &

(echo title; echo "empty line"; echo "1. option"; echo "2. option" ; echo "3. All Versions"; sleep 10 ) > count &

pid=$!                                  #get the pid of the subshell
disown                                  #to avoid the untidy kill output
sleep 1                                 #just allow time for the subshell output
kill -9 $pid                            #kill the dummy process
option=$(grep -i "all versions" count | grep -Po "[^0-9]*[0-9]+")  
                                        #grab the option want from the output
rm count                                #tidy up
echo $option | gem etc....        #launch gem with the known option
```

Comment: This solution assumes we already know where `All versions` would lie(On 3 statically I assume). But that is not the case, we are looking to find out the Number on which `All versions` is written and then input the Number to proceed and delete all bundler versions.

Comment: Whichever line contains the text `all versions` will be extracted complete to a variable and then you parse the extracted line for the number at the start. The only assumption here is that there are no more than 9 options since I have only taken the first digit (`${option:0:1}`). I just threw in the example line as a test. Change the number against the `all versions` option, or the sequence of the options and you will see.

Comment: Edited to allow for larger numbers and leading whitespace